# Align line a parallel to line b related to rotation point p

Tags: python, geometry, lines, geogebra

I need to align two lines a(A,B) and b(C,D) so that they are parallel to each other. Rotation point P can be outside the lines, so that both lines would share same rotation point. Python or Geogebra solution is preferred. In case of Geogebra, CAS operations are fine. Solution ie. rotation angle should be in degrees and reoriented line b(C,D) new coordinates c(E,F).

Provided illustration to clarify the problem:

[image: Parallel lines]

Comment: What does this mean: ` linear to each other` - parallel? It would be good to see illustration.

Comment: Yes, parallel. I need to correct the word and set up a figure.

Comment: Illustration added

Answer (score 1):

1 Get direction vectors of  lines

```
dAB = (B.X - A.X, B.Y - A.Y)
dCD = (D.X - C.X, D.Y - C.Y)
```

2  Find angle needed to make lines parallel using scalar and cross products

```
Theta = Math.ArcTan2(Cross(dAB, dCD), Dot(dAB, dCD)) = 
        Math.ArcTan2(dAB.X * dCD.Y - dAB.Y * dCD.X, dAB.X * dCD.X + dAB.Y * dCD.Y)
```

3 Rotate points C and D about center P (at you picture rotated segment is AB, In that case use negative angle `-Theta`)

```
C'.X = P.X + (C.X - P.X) * Cos(Theta) - (C.Y - P.Y) * Sin(Theta) 
C'.Y = P.Y + (C.X - P.X) * Sin(Theta) + (C.Y - P.Y) * Cos(Theta) 
the same for D
```

Comment: Thanks for splitting cross and dot products down to the point presentation. This works like charm in GeoGebra too. I always forget to ask this, but what did you study for being able to solve the case?

Comment: Basics of vector algebra/geometry and affine transformations for 3rd paragraph

Answer (score 0):

[image]

firstly, u should know the angle to rotate. the angle consists of p_p1 and p_p2 is your need.

to get the p1 or p2

```
bool PointProjectToLine(const cv::Point2f& point_to_proj, const cv::Point2f& line_pt1,
const cv::Point2f& line_pt2, cv::Point2f& project_pt) {
  float x12 = line_pt2.x - line_pt1.x;
  float y12 = line_pt2.y - line_pt1.y;

  float dot_p = x12 * (point_to_proj.x - line_pt1.x) + y12 * (point_to_proj.y- line_pt1.y);
  float dot12 = x12 * x12 + y12 * y12;

  if (std::abs(dot12) < 1e-4) {
    return false;
  } else {
    float coeff = dot_p / dot12;
    project_pt.x = line_pt1.x + x12 * coeff;
    project_pt.y = line_pt1.y + y12 * coeff;
    return true;
  } }
```

to get the angle between p_p1 and p_p2:

```
int LineDegreeRef(cv::Point2f lineRefStartPt, cv::Point2f lineRefEndPt, 
    cv::Point2f line1StartPt, cv::Point2f line1EndPt, double& angle) {
double x1 = lineRefEndPt.x - lineRefStartPt.x;
double y1 = lineRefEndPt.y - lineRefStartPt.y;

double x2 = line1EndPt.x - line1StartPt.x;
double y2 = line1EndPt.y - line1StartPt.y;

angle = std::atan2(y1, x1) - std::atan2(y2, x2);
if (angle > M_PI) {
    angle -= 2 * M_PI;
} else if (angle <= -M_PI) {
    angle += 2 * M_PI;
}
angle = -angle;  // anti_cw is positive

return 0;  }
```

now, just rotate the point A and Point B by the angle.

```
int pt_rotate(cv::Size size, cv::Point ptIn, cv::Point rotCenter, cv::Point& ptOut, float theta) {
    int row = size.height;
    int col = size.width;
    int x1 = ptIn.x;
    int y1 = ptIn.y;
    int x2 = rotCenter.x;
    int y2 = rotCenter.y;
    int x = ptOut.x;
    int y = ptOut.y;

    x1 = x1;
    y1 = row - y1;
    x2 = x2;
    y2 = row - y2;
    x = (x1 - x2)*cos(CV_PI / 180.0 * theta) - (y1 - y2)*sin(CV_PI / 180.0 * theta) + x2;
    y = (x1 - x2)*sin(CV_PI / 180.0 * theta) + (y1 - y2)*cos(CV_PI / 180.0 * theta) + y2;
    x = x;
    y = row - y;

    ptOut.x = x;
    ptOut.y = y;

    return 0;   }
```

finally, answer is show up. btw, direction of angle may influence your result. sorry for cpp code not python, but transform is easy.